# Uniform continuity for $f(x) = 2x + \arctan(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f(x) = 2x + \arctan(x)$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Differentiating $f$ I get that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-1}+2 \le 3$. Now from the mean value theorem I get that $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(c)||x-y| \le 3|x-y|$$ which would mean that $f$ is $3-$Lipschitz and thus uniformly continuous?

Comment: Except for  a typo it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a perfectly fine argument, indeed Lipschitz continuity implies uniform continuity. Note the converse is not true (can you guess an example?).

Just for curiosity, notice the following characterization of uniform continuity is true:

A function $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $\Omega$ convex and bounded is uniformly continuous if and only if it is *almost Lipschitz*.

Definition: $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is almost Lipschitz if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $K >0$ such that $$|f(x)-f(y)|< K|x-y| + \varepsilon$$ for all $x,y \in \Omega$